# Сохранение изменений введённых данных в таблицу при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, table

Всем здравствуйте! Нужна помощь.
Есть таблица, но при обновлении страницы, она обнуляется. Какой функцией можно это исправить?
Пара моментов:

1. Таблица должна обнуляться с началом следующих суток.
2. Можно ли сохранять введённые данные в текстовом файле (или лучше не в .txt)?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  <title>КПП</title>
</head>
  <h1>Журнал</h1>
  <a href="pages/narad.html"><h2>Страница 2</h2></a>
  <div id="current_date_time_block"></div>
  <div id="current_date_time_block2"></div>
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead id="tableHeader"><!--ряд с ячейками заголовков-->
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="botton_add" onclick="addNewRow()">Добавить строку</button>
  <button type="button" id="botton_save" onclick="saveTable()">Сохранить</button>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
    /* функция получения текущей даты и времени */
    function zero_first_format(value) {
        return (value < 10) ? value='0'+value : value;
    }
    
    function date_time(){
        const current_datetime = new Date();
        const day = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getDate());
        const month = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMonth()+1);
        const year = current_datetime.getFullYear();
        const hours = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getHours());
        const minutes = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMinutes());
        const seconds = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getSeconds());
        return `${day}.${month}.${year} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
    /* выводим текущую дату и время */
    setInterval(function () {
          document.getElementById('current_date_time_block2').innerHTML = date_time();           
      }, 1000);
    
    
    const tableHeader = document.getElementById('tableHeader');
    const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
    const NO_DATA = " ";
    
    // блок данных
    const jurnalRows = [
      [1,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
    ]
    const lastNames =[
      NO_DATA,
      "Иванов А.А.",
      "Петров В.В.",
      "Cидоров Д.Е."
    ];
    const models =[
       NO_DATA,
       "Жигули о000оо",
       "Волга ч000чч",
       "Лада х000хх"
    ];
    
    const columns = [ 
        {name: "№ п/п", source:null, className:"number"},
        {name: "Фамилия водителя", source:createSelect(lastNames), dataSource: lastNames, className: "lastName"},
        {name: "Марка / № машины", source:createSelect(models), dataSource: models, className: "model"},
        {name: "№ путевого листа", source:createInput('text'), dataSource: "", className:"listNumber"},
        {name: "Время выезда", source:createInput('time'), dataSource: "time", className:"timeOut"},
        {name: "Начальный километраж", source:createInput('number'), dataSource: 0, className: "begin"},
        {name: "Конечный километраж", source:createInput('number'), dataSource: 0,  className: "end"},
        {name: "Время заезда", source:createInput('time'), dataSource: "time", className:"timeIn"},
        {name: "Пройдено км", source:null, className: "sum"}        
    ]
    // конец блока данных
    
    // блок переменных
    let currentRow = -1;
    let currentCol = -1;
    let currentCell = null;
    const indexOfSum = columns.indexOf(columns.find( e => e.className === "sum"));
    const indexOfBegin = columns.indexOf(columns.find( e => e.className === "begin"));
    const indexOfEnd = columns.indexOf(columns.find( e => e.className === "end"));
    // конец блока переменных
    
    // подсчет колонки "Пройдено км"    
    function calulate(event) {
      const cell = event.target;
      if (cell.parentNode.className === "begin") {
        jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfSum] = jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfEnd] - cell.value;
      } else if (cell.parentNode.className === "end") {
        jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfSum] = cell.value - jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfBegin];
      } 
      tableBody.children[currentRow].children[indexOfSum].textContent = jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfSum]
    }
    
    function createInput(type) {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', type);
      input.addEventListener('change', calulate, false);
      return input;
    }
    
    function createSelect(list) {
        const select = document.createElement('select');
        select.cla
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value=i;
            option.textContent=list[i];
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        return select;
    }
    
    const createCell = (text, className) => {
      const cell = document.createElement('td'); 
      cell.textContent=text
      if(className) cell.className = className;
      return cell;
    }
    
    const createHeader = () => {
      const row = document.createDocumentFragment();
      for (i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){
       const cell = createCell(columns[i].name, columns[i].className);
       row.appendChild(cell);
      }
      return row;
    }
    
    const createRow = (rowData) => {
      const row = document.createElement('tr'); 
      for (i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){
       const cell= createCell(rowData[i], columns[i].className);
       row.appendChild(cell);
      }
      return row
    }
    
    function addNewRow() {
        const rowData = [jurnalRows.length +1, ...Array(columns.length-1).fill(NO_DATA)];
        jurnalRows.push(rowData)
        tableBody.appendChild(createRow(rowData))
    }
    
    function addRow(rowData) {
      tableBody.appendChild(createRow(rowData))
    }
    
    const fillTable = () => {
      tableHeader.appendChild(createHeader())
      for (let i = 0; i < jurnalRows.length; i++){
        addRow(jurnalRows[i])
      }
      //addNewRow()
    }
    
    fillTable()
    
    const showEditField = () => {
      if (event.target.tagName !== 'TD') return;
      const cell = event.target;
      const column = columns.find(e => e.className === cell.className);
      const index = columns.indexOf(column);
      // запоминаем последний выбор в данных
      if (currentCell && currentCol !== -1 && currentRow !== -1){
        if (Array.isArray(columns[currentCol].dataSource)){
          jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol] = columns[currentCol].dataSource[+columns[currentCol].source.value];
          currentCell.textContent = jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol];                 
        } else {
          jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol] = columns[currentCol].source.value;
          currentCell.textContent = jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol];                 
        }
      }
      // переносим ячейку выбора
      if (column.source) {
        oldData = cell.innerHTML;
        cell.innerHTML = "";
        if (Array.isArray(column.dataSource)){
          column.source.value = `${column.dataSource.indexOf(oldData)}`;
        } else {
          column.source.value = oldData !== NO_DATA ? oldData : column.dataSource;
        }
        cell.appendChild(column.source)
        currentCol = index;
        currentRow = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tableBody.children, cell.parentNode);
        currentCell = cell;
        // console.table(jurnalRows);
      }       
    }
    tableBody.addEventListener('click',showEditField, false)
```

Comment: Если серверная часть не принимает никаких данных, то вы можете внесённые изменения сохранять в localStorage

Comment: @ ArchDemon пока без сервера, локально можно что-то сделать?

Comment: Я вам уже написал - localStorage

Comment: а можно ещё использовать webSql и IndexedDB  :)  Это, кстати, тоже в браузере)))